# How to get TTL or expired document in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I want to create ticketing system . Where ticket get cancelled after given period of time ?.For deleting after some time I am going to use indexing feature by MongoDb . But before it gets expire or after the expiry of that particular ticket I want to retrive or save it in different collection for future  is it possible using mongodb ?

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible using mongodb"? Plain queries you mean?

Comment: I think you have to do that programmatically since mongodb does not offer this feature out of the box. You may use the oplog collection and see if you can recover the previously deleted documents ? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/

Comment: I suggest you have a helper app that sits in a loop and every 5 minutes wakes up and find tickets to expire, at which point it will update their status to `expired` or similar.   You don't want to deal with TTL and the mechanics of "saving for future."  Also, this will permit far greater logic expressivity in case something in the ticket warrants deferring expiry in that cycle (e.g. ticket is actually now in "being work on" state)

Comment: @Gibbs I mean , How to do this feature using mongodb ? Is there any existing feature given by the mongoDb ?.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of MongoDB, 5.0.8 as I'm writing this, it's not directly supported, but it will be in MongoDB 6.0 (CF this [jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36941)) and there is a workaround that you can use in the meantime (keep reading!).

Let me explain. What you are trying to do is:

- set up a [TTL index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/) that will remove automatically the docs in your MongoDB collection when the time is passed by X seconds.
- set up a [Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) on this collection with a filter set to only keep delete operations.

In 5.0.8, this change stream event will only contain the `_id` field of the deleted document, and nothing else, as that's the only information currently available in the oplog.

In 6.0, you will be able to access the previous state of this document (so it's last state before being deleted).

That being said, there is a workaround that Pavel Duchovny explained in his [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/triggers-tricks-data-driven-schedule/). You can easily accommodate his notification system to achieve your desired behaviour.